# Angular getting Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'

Tags: angular, build

When I do ng serve in my newly created angular project I get this:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that did solves the trick:

```
1. npm update -g @angular/cli
2. editing my package.json changing the line
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
to
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
3. npm update
```

Many thanks to certain Lars Mengel - I followed his advice.